# How to find and replace the whole word (exact match) from a string in python using "re" package while the string contains the metacharacter?

Tags: python, regex, string

For example,

```
line = "array[0] is the first element, array[0]some_character, is not a valid element"
```

I just want to find and replace `"array[0]"` in the string. In this case, let's assume, I want to replace it with the word `"element1"`. Then the output should be as follows:

```
line = "element1 is the first element, array[0]some_character, is not a valid element".
```

Please notice that, in the string, `array[0]some_character` should be unchanged, it should not be replaced like `"element1some_character"`

I appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
word = "abcd ab[0]c ab[0] class ab[0]d classified ab[0]"
re.sub(r'ab\[0\](\s|$)', r'ahmed\1', word)
```

Output:

`'abcd ab[0]c ahmed class ab[0]d classified ahmed'`

Or Using look-ahead

```
word = "abcd ab[0]c ab[0] class ab[0]d classified ab[0]"
re.sub(r'ab\[0\](?=\s|$)', r'ahmed', word)
```

Output:

`'abcd ab[0]c ahmed class ab[0]d classified ahmed'`

Comment: Hi, it works, but it has a little issue. If the string is like word = "abcd ab[0]c ab[0], class ab[0]d classified ab[0]": a comma is places right after ab[0], then it does not consider ab[0] a whole word.

Answer (score 0):

`t = "array[0] is the first element, array[0]some_character, is not a valid element"
re.sub("a[a-z]+\[[0-9]+\](?=[\s]{1})", "Element1", t)`

you see at the end of regex - (?=[\s]{1}), no white space followed the second array[0], so it won't be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

line = "array[0] is the first element, second is array[0], array[0]some_character, is not valid element array[0]."
res = re.sub(r'\barray\[0\](?!\w)', 'REPL', line)
print res
```

**Output:**

```
REPL is the first element, second is REPL, array[0]some_character, is not valid element REPL.
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b              # word boundary, to not match isarray[0]
array\[0\]      # the string to match
(?!\w)          # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a word character after
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/Zd8pYS/1)

Comment: @Ahmed: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

line = "array[0] is the first element, array[0]some_character, is not a valid element"
re.sub('array\[0\]\s','element1 ',line)
```

Output: 
'element1 is the first element, array[0]some_character, is not a valid element'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.